# Cannot set HP Pavilion Boot Manager to Boot from External CD/DVD drive

Tags: boot, hp-pavilion

I am trying to restore an HP Pavilion 15 Notebook(2014 vintage) which was running Windows 8.1 before a disk head crash, which required me to replace the internal HDD. When I try to re-install Windows from a set of 3 Windows 8 recovery media using an external DVD/CD drive (the internal one having died long ago) I do not see an option in Boot Manager to boot from a USB CD/DVD ROM even though I have changed the UEFI Boot order to have the USB CD/DVD ROM Drive option at the head of the list, and CD-ROM Boot is enabled in the Boot Options screen of BIOS (or rather InsydeH20 Setup Utility). The only options are OS Boot Manager and Boot from EFI File. There is a legacy boot order which has the USB CD/DVD ROM drive at the end of the list but this is greyed out. How can I get the machine to boot from an external USB CD/DVD ROM drive?

Answer (score 0):

HP [suggests, to boot from USB](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Change-Boot-Sequence-and-How-to-Boot-from-USB/td-p/6132655):

- As soon as you press the power-on button, *immediately* begin *tapping* <kbd>Esc</kbd>, which should open the HP *Startup Menu*.
- Choose <kbd>F9</kbd> to open *Boot Device* options
- If BIOS can see the USB device, it should appear as an option
- **If the USB boot device does not show in the list, or is grayed out,** it is likely due to *Secure Boot* and/or *Legacy Mode* settings. [To allow the media to be seen](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03653226):

  - Enter BIOS <kbd>F10</kbd> [may differ on the Pavillion].
  - Ensure *Secure Boot* is disabled.
  - Ensure Legacy mode is enabled.
  - Save the UEFI/BIOS changes.
  - Reboot and go to *Boot Device* as above.

That said, I'd [download the latest Windows 8.1 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO) and install to flash USB drive, using [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool).

Well, actually, I'd abandon Windows 8.1, if at all feasible, and move to more modern Windows 10 or a Linux distro, such as [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (Linux tends to run better on older machines that may be *slow* on Windows 10).

Details>> http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03653226

Comment: Took your advice and created a Win 10 installer on a USB.  Was able to install Win10 OK but now I have a problem with the touchpad (and external USB mouse) stopping responding for about 0.5 sec every 1 sec, making the machine very difficult to use. Tried a few solutions for jerky mouse but none have worked so far. Will post another question about this.